# Android How to check for app update when we don't have any server?

Tags: android, dropbox

First of all I am sorry this is not exactly programming related question but want a solution.

I am designing an application which is not on Play Store and I don't even own a server. I want to check once a week for application update. If an update is available I want to show a dialog, on click of which, my app will download the new apk which is stored on say Dropbox.

So can I do that?

Comment: If you don't have a server & don't use Google Play store, where should the App ask is there an update?

Comment: Exactly that's what my question is. I publish my app myself though say CDs. Now, I can not reach every customer when a new update is available. Instead, I'd simply put a check in my application about app update and if an update is available, I'd ask the user to download it from given location, e.g. Dropbox Public Link.

Comment: parse.com has alot of features but one of them, is sending a Message from a web console to your App users. Don't know if it's worth to hassle with it for your project, but if its small enough it's free.

Comment: Have you checked GCM: http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A simple way to do this would be to add a text file to Dropbox containing the versionCode of your new APK.

You can download that and compare it to the currently installed version.

PS Version details can be retrieved from [PackageManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593592/get-application-version-programatically-in-android).

Comment: Yes, this can be a solution but this will require that user enables dropbox sync. If he denies to do so, this method will not help me. Anyways, thanks a lot. I'd go with your solution if nothing else works for me.

Comment: You can download a Dropbox file over HTTP like any other webpage. https://www.dropbox.com/help/20/en

Comment: Ohh yes. That's a good idea. Thanks @alex. Accepted and upvoted. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without your own Server it really is weird.

You either have to create a Dropbox Account for your App, and then use dropbox api to connect to that Account and check the Lastmodified Date of your apk uploaded there - or use a service + library like parse.com where you can send Message to all your App Users.

Comment: Yes, I agree its kinda weird. But frankly speaking I don't sell this app and thus don't want to buy any server space just for a fun app. But still want to make this app better. Anyways, thanks a lot. I'd go with @alex 's solution if nothing else works for me.