# How to retrieve Glass XE version number?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

How can I retrieve information about Google Glass with GDK, e.g. which software update is currently installed on Google Glass ?

Answer (score 3):

You can do this via adb

```
adb shell getprop ro.build.version.glass
//XE12 

adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release
//4.0.4
```

To get it programmatically IE (if XE10) do this else if (XE12)...

Follow this lead [Get application version programmatically in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593592/get-application-version-programatically-in-android)