# Access versionName in build.gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle, android-studio

Is there a way to access `versionName` in my `build.gradle` from xml? I would like to set a `TextView`'s text with this value.

Or maybe declare a string with the version in `strings.xml` and use that in `build.gradle`?

Is there nothing simple like `@android:strings:version`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get application version programatically in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593592/get-application-version-programatically-in-android)

Comment: Take a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593592/get-application-version-programatically-in-android

Comment: Read the question. I'm asking for the versionname from build.gradle so I can access it in my xml

Comment: So you want to edit xml instead of build.gradle? So gradle will put this value in your AndroidManifest

Comment: You can use gradle.properties inside your root project and define:

VERSION_NAME=1.2.1
VERSION_CODE=26
Then in your build.gradle you can use:

versionName project.VERSION_NAME
versionCode Integer.parseInt(project.VERSION_CODE)

Comment: Thanks. Please post as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `BuildConfig` class for this. For example:

```
TextView mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mTv);
mTv.setText(BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME);
```

or

```
Toast.makeText(this, BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```