# Grails access variable in build.gradle from Service class

Tags: grails, gradle, build.gradle, grails-3.1

I am sitting in front of a Grails 3.1.4 Application. The `build.gradle` file looks like this:

```
buildscript {
    ...
}


version "01.01.12.99"

...

ext {
    ...
}

repositories {
    ...
}

dependencyManagement {
    ...
}

dependencies {
    ...
}
```

From one of my Service Classes I want to access the `version` variable. Is this somehow built in into Grails or am I trying to do something impossible? Are there ways to load this variable from a Service class?

I searched a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24202194/access-versionname-in-build-gradle), but it accesses the Grails version not the project version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I recently started using Grails 3. Here I got the solution:

```
println System.properties.getProperty("info.app.version")
```

And you will get `"01.01.12.99"`. This is working on Grails 3.1.8 for me.

Comment: Although this works when running the Grails application locally with `bootRun`, it doesnt work when creating the war file and deploying it to a server. The latter returns always `null`. Do you have an idea how to make this work for a deployed war file?

Comment: Have you tried printing the `System.properties` in the build ?

Answer (score 1):

Another way to achieve this (in addition to the solution provided by Shashank Agrawal) is relying on **grailsApplication** bean, with the following code:

```
grailsApplication.config.getProperty('info.app.version')
```

I tested this with Grails 3.1.9 and 3.2.7.