# How to get build version from third party app

Tags: android, version

You Guys have any idea how to get the Build Version of a third Party app Programmatically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get application version programatically in android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6593592/get-application-version-programatically-in-android)

Comment: No the other question is considering the Problem to get the app's Version number, however not the Version number of a third Party app

Comment: It's the same, you need to change `getPackageName()` to the package name you want to check though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the build/version number of your android application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616095/how-to-get-the-build-version-number-of-your-android-application)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `PackageInfo.versionName` to get 3rd party app's version.
My example:

```
List<PackageInfo> packages = getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
for (PackageInfo packageInfo : packages) {
    System.out.println(packageInfo.versionName);
}
```